# cocos2d ccparticlesystem .... speed low

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

i have this bubble that i want to show emerging from the bottom but the speed is too fast i want to slow down the speed to minimum the code is ..

```
   emitter2.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"Bubbles-1.png"];
    emitter2.position = ccp(size.width/2,-200);
    // gravity
    emitter2.gravity = CGPointMake(-10, 1000);

    // angle
    emitter2.angle = 95;
    emitter2.angleVar = 360;

    // speed of particles
    emitter2.speed = 1 ;//80;
    emitter2.speedVar = 1;

    // radial
    emitter2.radialAccel = -120;
    emitter2.radialAccelVar = 0;

    // tagential
    emitter2.tangentialAccel = 30;
    emitter2.tangentialAccelVar = 0;

    // life of particles
    emitter2.life = 2;
    emitter2.lifeVar = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decrease your gravity!!!!

```
emitter2.gravity = CGPointMake(-10, 1); //1000 is a bit to much for bubbles ;o)
```

Comment: what does gravity do exactly isnt it the area of movement of bubble ...please help @Chakalaka

Comment: gravity do exaclty the same as gravity do on earth. the reason why you cant fly or sometimes fall to the ground ;) it accelerates the bubbles